# Trying to create AI - Some IF statement not catching

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make an AI and for some reason I cant get the IF statements to catch the code.

Alice.py

```
import games
from function import *

startup()
main()
```

My problem is in the main() function.

```
def main()
    life = True
    while life == True:
        request = input('-> ')
        if request.startswith('play'):
            request.replace('play ', '', 1)
            if request == 'guess the number':
                games.guess_the_number(u_name)
            elif request == 'test':
                print('Test')
        if request == 'quit':
            print('Goodbye')
            return
```

I can't seem to get the first IF block to opereate the way I want. It just returns no output.
I have tried everything and I just can't seem to get it to work. Amy help would be amazing. I'll gladly answer any questions anyone has.

Comment: Exactly what doesn't return an output and what exactly isn't working here? Is the if-statement not being entered or is something inside your if statement not working? Your not storing the output of any method anywhere in your code. We don't have the code for: `games.guess_the_number(u_name)`. Including the value of  `u_name`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: All of everything else is working. 
if I was to type 'play guess the number' or 'play test' nothing happens.

Comment: You're entering the if-statement fine. When you do `request.replace` you need to assign the result like this: `request = request.replace(...)`. The `request.replace(...)` will produce a result, but it's not stored anywhere and doesn't change `request` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Change `request.replace('play ', '', 1)` to `request = request.replace('play ', '', 1)`. What you currently have will produce an output string with the word `"play"` removed, but it does not get stored anywhere. `str.replace(..)` does not change the value of `str`, instead it simply gives a string output which you assign to a variable. In this case you can assign it back to `request`:

```
    ...
    request = input('-> ')
    if request.startswith('play'):
        request = request.replace('play ', '', 1)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Env: Python 2.7.12

This is because when you are doing replace there is temporary replace of the string in your main input and the change is not saved in the `request` string.
Look below for example.

```
>>> req = input('-> ')
    -> "play guess the number"
>>> if req.startswith('play'):
...     req.replace('play ', '', 1)
... 
 'guess the number'
>>> req
 'play guess the number'
>>> if req.startswith('play'):
...     req = req.replace('play ', '', 1)
... 
>>> req
'guess the number'
```

I guess this answers your question, It's just that you have to update the `request` variable.